# How to fix 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: username for django graphene authentication endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, graphene-python, django-graphql-auth

In my Django application I have created customer user model which uses email as username.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True,)

    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
    )
```

I am using graphene for APIs. For authentication endpoint I am following below steps,
https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

I am keep getting below error,

```
sports_league-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 71, in __new__
sports_league-web-1  |     new_class.base_filters = new_class.get_filters()
sports_league-web-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 358, in get_filters
sports_league-web-1  |     raise TypeError(
sports_league-web-1  | TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: username
```

Kindly advise what I am doing wrong here. Let me know if any other details needed.

Comment: Why is `username = None` remove it

Comment: I did remove the username field but still getting the same issue,

This tutorial I used to create User model
https://heemayl.net/posts/django-custom-user-model-without-username-field-and-using-email-in-place-of-it/

And this tutorial to setup authentication
https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

Comment: please post another question with the details of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved this issue.

Modify the app settings file by adding below,

```
from graphql_auth.settings import DEFAULTS

DEFAULTS['LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS'] = ['email']
DEFAULTS['REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS'] = ['email']
DEFAULTS['USER_NODE_FILTER_FIELDS'] = {
    'email': ['exact'],
    'is_active': ['exact'],
    'status__archived': ['exact'],
    'status__verified': ['exact'],
    'status__secondary_email': ['exact'],
}
GRAPHQL_AUTH = DEFAULTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove username field in your model as you have setup email as username:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True,)

    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid4,
        unique=True,
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your custom user class "User"** doesn't have **"username" field** so you need to remove **"username" field** from **"GRAPHQL_AUTH" settings** which are set **"username" field** by default.

So, by default, **"username" field** is set to [**"LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS"**](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#login_allowed_fields), [**"REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS"**](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#register_mutation_fields) and [**"USER_NODE_FILTER_FIELDS"**](https://django-graphql-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings/#user_node_filter_fields) in **"GRAPHQL_AUTH" settings** as shown below:

```py
GRAPHQL_AUTH = {                      # ↓ Here
    'LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS': ["email", "username"],
    'REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS': ["email", "username"],
    'USER_NODE_FILTER_FIELDS': {          # ↑ Here
        "email": ["exact"],
        "username": ["exact", "icontains", "istartswith"], # ← Here
        "is_active": ["exact"],
        "status__archived": ["exact"],
        "status__verified": ["exact"],
        "status__secondary_email": ["exact"],
    }
}
```

So, to remove **"username" field** from them, you need to redefine them in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

GRAPHQL_AUTH = {
    'LOGIN_ALLOWED_FIELDS': ['email'],
    'REGISTER_MUTATION_FIELDS': ['email'],
    'USER_NODE_FILTER_FIELDS': { 
        "email": ["exact"], 
        "is_active": ["exact"],
        "status__archived": ["exact"],
        "status__verified": ["exact"],
        "status__secondary_email": ["exact"],
    }
}
```